# ImageView in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-linearlayout

I have two problems with this layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@null">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/image1"
            android:id="@+id/image1"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:background="@drawable/card_background"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/image2"
            android:id="@+id/image2"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:background="@drawable/card_background"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            />
</LinearLayout>
```

when I put different Images in the ImageViews , this happened :

- The ImageViews height is greater than 130dp however I put the height as (match_parent) and the parent height is 130dp .
- The ImageViews width is not the same , however the both of ImageViews has the same weight , but the larger one  takes more width than the other .

Comment: you have not given a weight_sum to parent layout

Comment: I did , and it's still the same

Comment: you mean images are not same in size or those views are not same in size ? you can use `scaletype=fitxy`  in imageViews to make images fit its boundries

Comment: show output image to clarify

Comment: when I put images with different size , the bigger one take more width than the smaller one , and the height of the both of Images match the ImageView which contain the bigger Image

Comment: you are setting background and src so it is confusing that are u talking about image or view

Comment: I am talking about the ImageView itself , u can delete the background attribute , it won't make a change ,

Comment: @Maysara If you set `android:scaleYpe="fitXY"` in each imageView's image they will be same in width as well but there is a possibility to stretch your image

Comment: unfortunately  , I need to use centerCrop

Comment: so what is your requirement i don't think that you can upscale it in another way!  then try to add image with background attribute

Comment: i just want the ImageViews to be the same in size despite  the size of the (src Image) .

Comment: if you use centerCrop then there will be difference in size if images are not of same size

Comment: @Omer so what is the solution ? I need to use centerCrop

Comment: `CENTER_CROP-Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect ratio) so that both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be equal to or larger than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus padding)`.  So you want center_crop and keep two different size images as the same size

Comment: @Charuka exactly , how can I do this?

Comment: not possible to maintain image's aspect ratio

Comment: @Omer there is always a soultion

Comment: true for @Omer, but you can use `android:adjustViewBounds=true`

Comment: @Charuka great ! , the first problem is solved , the height of all ImageViews is 130 dp now ,,, but the second problem is unsolved

Comment: @Maysara I dont think there is a way inbuilt , to solve that :) thats the ratio , only way is fitXY witch really fits but it ll stretch a bit

Comment: there is an answer , I deserve +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code works , why ?
I don't really know .

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:background="@null"
    >
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            >
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="130dp"
                android:id="@+id/image2"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/offer_mix_small_1"
                />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:background="@color/secondary_text_color"
            >
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="130dp"
                android:id="@+id/image1"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/offer_land"
                />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

You forget to add weightsum in root layout so add this line in root layout.

```
android:weightSum="1"
```

Its like like after adding weight sum

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@null">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/image1"
            android:id="@+id/image1"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:background="@drawable/card_background"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/image2"
            android:id="@+id/image2"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:background="@drawable/card_background"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            />
</LinearLayout>
```